# scss error expected media query

Tags: css, sass

Im doing a scss mixin for media query

```
@mixin breakpoints($min-width, $max-width, $media-type: false) {
  @if $media-type == true {
    @media $media-type and (min-width: $min-width) and (max-width: $max-width) {
      @content;
    }
  } @else {
    @media all and (min-width: $min-width) and (max-width: $max-width) {
      @content;
    }
  }
}
```

`$media-type` is false as default, if i dont want to specify it when calling mixin. If `$media-type` is passed in mixin then i want to that variable to be printed after @media. So if i include mixin `@include breakpoints(400, 600, only screen)`, as result i want `@media only screen and..`

when i try to test my mixin on sassmeister, i get this error:

```
Invalid CSS after "    @media ": expected media query (e.g. print, screen, print and screen), was "$media-type and..."
```

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out a way to do it to work without having to specify if statement for each media type.

```
@mixin breakpoints($min-width, $max-width, $media-type: false) {
  @if $media-type {
    @media #{$media-type} and (min-width: $min-width) and (max-width: $max-width) {
      @content;
    }
  } @else {
    @media all and (min-width: $min-width) and (max-width: $max-width) {
      @content;
    }
  }
}
```

the key was in #{$media-type}. now everything works, but i dont know how correct my solution is.

now i can call the mixin with

```
@include breakpoints(400, 600, only screen)
```

and

```
@include breakpoints(400, 600, 'only screen')
```

and

```
@include breakpoints(400, 600)
```

which will bring back the all keyword

Comment: Yes this is proper scss implementation of what you were trying to accomplish.

Comment: You will have to mark your own answer as correct, though :)

Answer (score 0):

Sass does not understand what you are trying to do when you pass back in the $media-type variable.  You will need to set an if statement for each 'media type' like:

```
@mixin breakpoints($min-width, $max-width, $media-type: false) {
  @if $media-type == print {
    @media print and (min-width: $min-width) and (max-width: $max-width) {
      @content;
    }
  } @else {
    @media all and (min-width: $min-width) and (max-width: $max-width) {
      @content;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: actually, i found a way to do it, could you please check if that is right way to do it, i will answer my own question in a minute

Comment: hey, thanks for your help, i put an answer, would you validate it?